# RaphaelJS like libraries for Flash/ActionScript?

Tags: animation, actionscript, raphael

Are there any third-party libraries like RaphaelJS (http://www.raphaeljs.com) for Flash that lets you draw and animate shapes using simple APIs?

Comment: You've got the default [Graphics API](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html) to start with. For Flex projects, Degrafa is handy: http://www.degrafa.org/samples/

Comment: As already mentioned you don't really need a library as the built in Graphics API can do most of what RaphaelJS can do, for animating I must recommend TweenMax or one of its sister libraries by GreenSock

Comment: Hi Neil,
You can post your reply as an answer. I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animating all kinds of objects in flash is easily achieved using the popular libraries over at [GreenSock](http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/)